# 2 computers cannot ping each other when connected to same VPN

Tags: windows-7, networking, ping

I have 2 computers. 1st computer's name is **SYED-HP** and 2nd computer's name is **SYED-PC**.

Both computers are part of same domain **ISLAND.LOCAL**. I login to both computers using same user name and password.

Both computers have same operating system **Windows 7 Professional Service Pack 1 (64-bit)**.

Both computers have **SonicWALL Net Extender** VPN client and connect to same VPN server.

After connection to the VPN server, 1st computer get **192.168.58.145** IP while the 2nd computer get **192.168.58.109** IP address.

In the 1st computer I open the cmd window as Administrator and try to ping the 2nd computer by its IP address but the request timed out. Same is the case when I try to ping 1st computer from 2nd computer.

How can I solve this problem?

### UPDATE:

On **cmd** prompt run `ipconfig /all` command in both computers. 
Both display under the ***PPP adapter SonicWALL NetExtender:*** heading, that the **Subnet Mask** is **255.255.255.255**.

Comment: What is your subnet mask (Looks like `255.255.255.0`)? Does your firewall allow ICMP packages (ping, etc.)? Does this VPN Client allow ICMP?

Comment: @NordlysJeger I have now mentioned subnet mask in the question. How to check the other 2 things you mentioned? I am not a network guy

Comment: Did Elbow Wizards answer solve all your problems, or do you still have issues? Sorry for not responding earlier

Answer (score 0):

Is your subnet mask truely 255.255.255.255, that could be where your issues are. I would try changing your subnet mask to 255.255.255.0 to see if that makes any difference.

If your subnet mask is truely 255.255.255.255 it means that your IP addresses are on different networks.

regards